# How do I remove the quote from a symbol in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I had to create a simple scheme program that outputs the contents of a binary tree.  I managed to complete the program but it outputs all the quotes with it.  How do I get rid of them?

```
(define bintree 
'(interior-node 
   'foo 
   (interior-node 'bar (leaf 26) (leaf 12)) 
   (interior-node 'baz (leaf 11) 
      (interior-node 'quux (leaf 117) (leaf 14)))))

(print-bintree bintree)  returns ('foo ('bar 26 12) ('baz 11 ('quux 117 14)))
```

I want it to return `(foo (bar 26 12) (baz 11 (quux 117 14)))` without the `'` mark on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the whole program (in particular, the definition of print-bintree), but it looks like a simple misunderstanding about how the quote works.

In particular, a quote before an open paren means that the contents of the parens are interpreted in a simple "data language", where sequences of characters are interpreted as symbols rather than variables.

To see what I mean, let's try evaluating some simple expressions

```
(zippy tong)
```

... produces some error about `zippy` and `tong` being undefined.

Now, try this:

```
'(zippy tong)
```

The result is going to depend a bit on your printer, but it will produce the same thing as

```
(list 'zippy 'tong)
```

That is, the leading quote means that `zippy` and `tong` are interpreted as symbols, rather than as variables.

In your code, you write:

```
'(interior-node 'foo ...)
```

The problem here is that you're using a quote when you're already inside a quoted expression. This isn't doing what you want. In particular, it will produce something equivalent to

```
(list 'interior-node (list 'quote 'foo) ...)
```

So, without getting any further into the magic of quote, it will probably suffice to remove the quotes from the `'foo`, `'bar`, etc. inside your definition of bintree.

Comment: Yeah.  I just realized that I was misreading the input and treating function names as symbols.